# What is the reason behind "has" in the sentence "One of us has done it"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In the sentence,

> One of us has done it.

We consider "one" as a third person. But why is this true?

The "one" is among "us." We know "Us" is the first person. So, why is "one" not first person also?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the questions in the body, please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: **One** of us **has** done it. -> **Two** of us **have** done it.

Comment: In this context, "one" is not a pronoun, it is the written form of the numeral "1"

Answer (score 1):

“Has” in this sentence is a helping verb that is used to help indicate the time “it” was done.

“One” is being used as a determiner in this sentence, not as a pronoun or noun that would indicate/change the point of view from 1st-, 2nd-, or 3rd- person point of view. For example, “Two of them have done it.” Two determines the number of them.

“One” when being used as a pronoun would be 3rd person because it would not generally be used in a sentence talking about yourself (1st-person POV) or the person you’re talking to (2nd-person POV). Example of “one” as a 3rd-person pronoun: “One cannot simply choose to exist.”